# How to select specific strings in a text file to be columns in a dataframe in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text

I've got a text file with scores for genes, organised like this:

```
[{"priorityType":"HIPHIVE_PRIORITY","geneId":367,"geneSymbol":"AR","score":1.0,"humanScore":1.0,"mouseScore":0.0,"fishScore":0.0,"ppiScore":0.0,"candidateGeneMatch":false,"queryPhenotypeTerms":[{"id":"HP:0003119","label":"Abnormal circulating lipid concentration"}],"phenotypeEvidence":[{"score":1.0,"model":{"organism":"HUMAN","entrezGeneId":367,"humanGeneSymbol":"AR","diseaseId":"ORPHA:481","diseaseTerm":"Kennedy disease","phenotypeIds":["HP:0000029","HP:0000144","HP:0000771","HP:0001252","HP:0001260","HP:0001265","HP:0001288","HP:0001618","HP:0003119","HP:0003202","HP:0005978","HP:0100639"],"id":"ORPHA:481_367"},"bestModelPhenotypeMatches":[{"query":{"id":"HP:0003119","label":"Abnormal circulating lipid concentration"},"match":{"id":"HP:0003119","label":"Abnormal circulating lipid concentration"},"lcs":{"id":"HP:0003119","label":"Abnormal circulating lipid concentration"},"ic":4.595759223970171,"simj":1.0,"score":2.1437721949801873}]}],"ppiEvidence":[]},
{"priorityType":"HIPHIVE_PRIORITY","geneId":2200,"geneSymbol":"FBN1","score":1.0,"humanScore":1.0,"mouseScore":0.0,"fishScore":0.0,"ppiScore":0.0,"candidateGeneMatch":false,"queryPhenotypeTerms":[{"id":"HP:0003119","label":"Abnormal circulating lipid concentration"}],"phenotypeEvidence":[{"score":1.0,"model":{"organism":"HUMAN","entrezGeneId":2200,"humanGeneSymbol":"FBN1","diseaseId":"ORPHA:2833","diseaseTerm":"Stiff skin syndrome","phenotypeIds":["HP:0000407","HP:0000486","HP:0000501","HP:0000541","HP:0000787","HP:0000822","HP:0001072","HP:0001324","HP:0001376","HP:0001482","HP:0003119","HP:0004322","HP:0005978","HP:0007328","HP:0008065","HP:0009830","HP:0011800","HP:0100578","HP:0100679"],"id":"ORPHA:2833_2200"},"bestModelPhenotypeMatches":[{"query":{"id":"HP:0003119","label":"Abnormal circulating lipid concentration"},"match":{"id":"HP:0003119","label":"Abnormal circulating lipid concentration"},"lcs":{"id":"HP:0003119","label":"Abnormal circulating lipid concentration"},"ic":4.595759223970171,"simj":1.0,"score":2.1437721949801873}]}],"ppiEvidence":[]},
{"priorityType":"HIPHIVE_PRIORITY","geneId":84823,"geneSymbol":"LMNB2","score":1.0,"humanScore":1.0,"mouseScore":0.0,"fishScore":0.0,"ppiScore":0.0,"candidateGeneMatch":false,"queryPhenotypeTerms":[{"id":"HP:0003119","label":"Abnormal circulating lipid concentration"}],"phenotypeEvidence":[{"score":1.0,"model":{"organism":"HUMAN","entrezGeneId":84823,"humanGeneSymbol":"LMNB2","diseaseId":"OMIM:608709","diseaseTerm":"Lipodystrophy, partial, acquired, susceptibility to","phenotypeIds":["HP:0000006","HP:0000093","HP:0000100","HP:0000147","HP:0000790","HP:0000793","HP:0000819","HP:0001007","HP:0002719","HP:0003119","HP:0003621","HP:0003745","HP:0005421","HP:0009002","HP:0009019","HP:0009056"],"id":"OMIM:608709_84823"},"bestModelPhenotypeMatches":[{"query":{"id":"HP:0003119","label":"Abnormal circulating lipid concentration"},"match":{"id":"HP:0003119","label":"Abnormal concentration"},"lcs":{"id":"HP:0003119","label":"Abnormal circulating lipid concentration"},"ic":4.595759223970171,"simj":1.0,"score":2.1437721949801873}]}],"ppiEvidence":[]}
```

I want to pull out the geneSymbol, score, humanScore, mouseScore, fishScore, and ppiScore, to have a dataframe like this:

```
geneSymbol   score   humanScore   mouseScore   fishScore   ppiScore
   AR         1.0      1.0          0.0           0.0      0.0 
   FBN1       1.0      1.0          0.0           0.0      0.0 
   LMNB2      1.0      1.0          0.0           0.0      0.0
```

I'm not experienced with python, and I've tried searching for similar questions to reapply other's code but I haven't found anything that I can get working.

My first problem is when I load my data into python it doesn't load each row as I see them in my text editor.

For example I am just running:

```
df = pd.read_csv("data.txt", sep="\t", header = None, encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
```

which reads in to look like:

[image]

I've noticed most of my rows end in []} - so I also tried defining a lineterminator, but this doesn't work:

```
df = pd.read_csv("data.txt", lineterminator='[]},', header = None, encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
ValueError: Only length-1 line terminators supported
```

I've also tried just separating rows by } but the error I then get is:

```
df = pd.read_csv("data.txt", lineterminator='}', header = None, encoding = "ISO-8859-1")

ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 11 fields in line 2, saw 20
```

How can I read in my data to then select the columns/create the dataframe I'm interested in?

I'm not sure on the best way to share example data, I've tried with my 3 example rows above to put them in `df.to_dict()` which outputs it as :

```
{0: {0: '{""priorityType"":""HIPHIVE_PRIORITY"",""geneId"":367,""geneSymbol"":""AR"",""score"":1.0,""humanScore"":1.0,""mouseScore"":0.0,""fishScore"":0.0,""ppiScore"":0.0,""candidateGeneMatch"":false,""queryPhenotypeTerms"":[{""id"":""HP:0003119"",""label"":""Abnormal circulating lipid concentration""}],""phenotypeEvidence"":[{""score"":1.0,""model"":{""organism"":""HUMAN"",""entrezGeneId"":367,""humanGeneSymbol"":""AR"",""diseaseId"":""ORPHA:481"",""diseaseTerm"":""Kennedy disease"",""phenotypeIds"":[""HP:0000029"",""HP:0000144"",""HP:0000771"",""HP:0001252"",""HP:0001260"",""HP:0001265"",""HP:0001288"",""HP:0001618"",""HP:0003119"",""HP:0003202"",""HP:0005978"",""HP:0100639""],""id"":""ORPHA:481_367""},""bestModelPhenotypeMatches"":[{""query"":{""id"":""HP:0003119"",""label"":""Abnormal circulating lipid concentration""},""match"":{""id"":""HP:0003119"",""label"":""Abnormal circulating lipid concentration""},""lcs"":{""id"":""HP:0003119"",""label"":""Abnormal circulating lipid concentration""},""ic"":4.595759223970171,""simj"":1.0,""score"":2.1437721949801873}]}],""ppiEvidence"":[]},{""priorityType"":""HIPHIVE_PRIORITY"",""geneId"":2200,""geneSymbol"":""FBN1"",""score"":1.0,""humanScore"":1.0,""mouseScore"":0.0,""fishScore"":0.0,""ppiScore"":0.0,""candidateGeneMatch"":false,""queryPhenotypeTerms"":[{""id"":""HP:0003119"",""label"":""Abnormal circulating lipid concentration""}],""phenotypeEvidence"":[{""score"":1.0,""model"":{""organism"":""HUMAN"",""entrezGeneId"":2200,""humanGeneSymbol"":""FBN1"",""diseaseId"":""ORPHA:2833"",""diseaseTerm"":""Stiff skin syndrome"",""phenotypeIds"":[""HP:0000407"",""HP:0000486"",""HP:0000501"",""HP:0000541"",""HP:0000787"",""HP:0000822"",""HP:0001072"",""HP:0001324"",""HP:0001376"",""HP:0001482"",""HP:0003119"",""HP:0004322"",""HP:0005978"",""HP:0007328"",""HP:0008065"",""HP:0009830"",""HP:0011800"",""HP:0100578"",""HP:0100679""],""id"":""ORPHA:2833_2200""},""bestModelPhenotypeMatches"":[{""query"":{""id"":""HP:0003119"",""label"":""Abnormal circulating lipid concentration""},""match"":{""id"":""HP:0003119"",""label"":""Abnormal circulating lipid concentration""},""lcs"":{""id"":""HP:0003119"",""label"":""Abnormal circulating lipid concentration""},""ic"":4.595759223970171,""simj"":1.0,""score"":2.1437721949801873}]}],""ppiEvidence"":[]},{""priorityType"":""HIPHIVE_PRIORITY"",""geneId"":84823,""geneSymbol"":""LMNB2"",""score"":1.0,""humanScore"":1.0,""mouseScore"":0.0,""fishScore"":0.0,""ppiScore"":0.0,""candidateGeneMatch"":false,""queryPhenotypeTerms"":[{""id"":""HP:0003119"",""label"":""Abnormal circulating lipid concentration""}],""phenotypeEvidence"":[{""score"":1.0,""model"":{""organism"":""HUMAN"",""entrezGeneId"":84823,""humanGeneSymbol"":""LMNB2"",""diseaseId"":""OMIM:608709"",""diseaseTerm"":""Lipodystrophy, partial, acquired, susceptibility to"",""phenotypeIds"":[""HP:0000006"",""HP:0000093"",""HP:0000100"",""HP:0000147"",""HP:0000790"",""HP:0000793"",""HP:0000819"",""HP:0001007"",""HP:0002719"",""HP:0003119"",""HP:0003621"",""HP:0003745"",""HP:0005421"",""HP:0009002"",""HP:0009019"",""HP:0009056""],""id"":""OMIM:608709_84823""},""bestModelPhenotypeMatches"":[{""query"":{""id"":""HP:0003119"",""label"":""Abnormal circulating lipid concentration""},""match"":{""id"":""HP:0003119"",""label"":""Abnormal circulating lipid concentration""},""lcs"":{""id"":""HP:0003119"",""label"":""Abnormal circulating lipid concentration""},""ic"":4.595759223970171,""simj"":1.0,""score"":2.1437721949801873}]}],""ppiEvidence"":[]'}}
```

Comment: This is a fairly complex data structure in JSON format.  What do you want to load from that data?  If the answer is 'everything' then it might be difficult.  You can do some subordinate element structure mapping to DF columns.  But you have some challenges like `phenotypeEvidence.model.phenotypeIds` is an array of values.  How would you want those represented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [`pd.DataFrame.from_records()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html). Load the file as a list of dictionaries and then pass to this function.